# Send an "internal" http request on Google App Engine

Tags: google-app-engine

I have built a Flask app with blueprints. I would like to make http calls between the different blueprints, which doesn't seem to work. The request keep timing out.

Is it not possible to make a http call inside a Google App Engine Service?

Here is my setup:

```
Blueprint 1
requests.post(url_for('asana_bp.create_task', _external=True), json=payload)


Blueprint 2
@asana_bp.route("/create", methods=["POST"])
@login_required
def create_task():
  data = request.get_json()
  return create_asana_task(message=data['message'], title=data['title'])
```

But this just doesn't work. Get a 502 error. It works perfectly fine. url_for creates the URL correctly.

Comment: Yes, you can do this and people do it all the time.

Comment: There is nothing special to it? just a normal http request?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the record.

The issue was memory. The instance was only a F1 small instance, which seems to be able to handle only one request at a time. So when doing an http request that will obviously start up a new instance, which is though to slow so the request times our or gets killed because the instance runs out of memory.

Solution is simple: Increase the instance size or just don't use http requests inside the same service.

A second possible issue could be @login_required. Not sure how session handling is happening on GAE accross multiple instances.